# Capture a wpf window : The flickering issue

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-capture

I made a simple animation (as crawl text) using C#-WPF.

The animation is smooth and excellent. (in wpf window)

But when I capture it by FFmpeg as video it has flickering problem.

Please see [sample1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7xJ3vpXXdvQVnFibXhfR2NQVUE/view?usp=sharing) (speed of animation is high) and [sample2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7xJ3vpXXdvQZ3hZc3c0WGgyZVU/view?usp=sharing) (speed of animation is low).

Is it field issue or sync problem or ......?

How can I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

this is my ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i title="Wpfwindow" -framerate 30 -vcodec libx264 out1.mp4 -y
```

**Note:**
I need to framerate=30 or framerate=25 , because I want to convert the video to PAL and NTSC formats.

Output of console:

```
ffmpeg version N-76417-gee20354 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
 built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavcodec     57. 13.102 / 57. 13.102
  libavformat    57. 13.100 / 57. 13.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 14.101 /  6. 14.101
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[gdigrab @ 000001df9916af40] Found window ooo, capturing 704x537x32 at (0,0)
Input #0, gdigrab, from 'title=Wpfwindow':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1464634804.659289, bitrate: 362576 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, bgra, 704x537, 362576 kb/s, 29.97 tbr, 1000k tbn, 29.97 tbc
No pixel format specified, yuv444p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.1, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] 264 - core 148 r2638 7599210 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.13.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv444p, 704x537, q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.13.102 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (bmp (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   16 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=   31 fps= 31 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=   46 fps= 31 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=   61 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=       5kB time=00:00:00.10 bitrate= 375.1kbits/s    
frame=   76 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=      11kB time=00:00:00.60 bitrate= 149.6kbits/s    
frame=   92 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=      22kB time=00:00:01.13 bitrate= 159.7kbits/s    
frame=  107 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=      28kB time=00:00:01.63 bitrate= 141.9kbits/s    
frame=  122 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=      36kB time=00:00:02.13 bitrate= 138.7kbits/s    
frame=  137 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=      44kB time=00:00:02.63 bitrate= 137.4kbits/s    
frame=  152 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=      48kB time=00:00:03.13 bitrate= 126.4kbits/s    
frame=  168 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=      52kB time=00:00:03.67 bitrate= 117.1kbits/s    
frame=  183 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=      55kB time=00:00:04.17 bitrate= 107.7kbits/s    
frame=  188 fps= 30 q=-1.0 Lsize=      74kB time=00:00:06.20 bitrate=  98.1kbits/s    
video:72kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 3.373045%
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] frame I:1     Avg QP:18.54  size:  2426
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] frame P:129   Avg QP:15.36  size:   483
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] frame B:58    Avg QP:22.37  size:   141
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] consecutive B-frames: 52.1% 20.2%  0.0% 27.7%
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] mb I  I16..4:  8.8% 88.0%  3.1%
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] mb P  I16..4:  0.8%  0.2%  0.2%  P16..4:  1.7%  0.7%  0.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:96.1%
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  2.0%  0.4%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:97.4%  L0:42.9% L1:46.7% BI:10.5%
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] 8x8 transform intra:44.1% inter:38.4%
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] coded y,u,v intra: 4.7% 5.2% 3.4% inter: 0.4% 0.4% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 87% 12%  1%  0%
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  8% 42% 50%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 60%  8% 23%  2%  2%  1%  2%  1%  1%
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] ref P L0: 56.0%  7.0% 17.4% 19.5%
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] ref B L0: 84.8% 10.7%  4.5%
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] ref B L1: 98.7%  1.3%
[libx264 @ 000001df9916db40] kb/s:93.00
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

`framerate` should go before `-i`, as it's telling ffmpeg what the input rate is.

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="Wpfwindow" -vcodec libx264 out1.mp4 -y
```

Comment: Thanks, but had no effect.
I've also used -r command :  `ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="Wpfwindow" -vcodec libx264 -r 30 out1.mp4 -y` , But this also does not work.

Comment: In your first sample, the amount of horizontal motion is not the same each frame. This could be an issue of low rate. Try 60. Don't add `-r` option, especially a value different than `framerate`.

Comment: And also try it with full desktop.

Comment: my animation has full framerate (FPS=60). aha ,ok . I'll try with full desktop.Thanks.